# R: plm package gmm estimation returns an error (simple first order model)

Tags: r, var

I am trying to compute a first order VAR model using the plm package, using first differences for the variables and the instruments. First, I am trying to solve the equation in respect to one variable, as I think the library only works in this fashion. The code I used is the following:

```
model <- pgmm(variable1~lag(variable2, 1) | lag(variable1, 1), data=d, effect="twoways", model="onestep", transformation = "ld")
```

R returns an error:

```
Error in solve.default(crossprod(WX, t(crossprod(WX, A2)))) : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.62316e-2
```

What is wrong with the equation? I have tried everything that comes to my mind. Specifically the part after the | sign interests me. I thought that the instruments are supposed to go there, but after reading the manual I am not sure exactly what is supposed to be put there.

Here is more info regarding the package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf // Pages 23 -->

EDIT: Upon restricting the model to "individual", I got a warning. I suppose everything is working fine as the result looks all right.

Comment: Hello Dole, I got the exact warning/error message. Did you dig deeper after the question? If changing "twoways" to "individual" works, what if I want a time fixed effect here in the model?

Comment: @Roger Unfortunately I can't recall anymore. But given the edit it seems like I simply ignored the message?

Answer (score 0):

If you shorten the sample period it is very likely that the error will not appear. For example, if it is a period from 1990-2020 it is very likely that it will be an error, but if you change the period to 1990-2000 the model will be computed.

### Heading

Comment: For the community to be able to help, please also post your code hopefully with the sample data and the specific error message.